# is it ok that i develop my website in cpanel? - is editting and coding in cpanel alright?

Tags: gitlab, cpanel

hello i want to know if it's good work to code your project in cpanel or not?

I'm doing this right now and sometimes i figured out that my file return back to yesterday's changes for example.

if it's not alright please suggest me some platform or environment that will be useful.

thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

cPanel provides many features: Awstats menu - helps to indicate the Bots or IPs on the websites, File Manager menu helps to save the files: " that my file return back to yesterday's changes for example" seems impossible for me, as it is simple storage place... Still, cPanel has the backup menu for your reference

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).